# Linear operator $T^k$ effect on $\operatorname{Ker}T^k$ and $\operatorname{Im}T^k$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:V\to V$, an linear operator.
In general, what can you say about $\operatorname{Ker}T^k$ and $\operatorname{Im}T^k$?

For example, I've understood that $\operatorname{KerT}^{k-1} \subseteq \operatorname{Ker}T^k$.

I'd like to know what else should I know? For, example about the dimensions of the kernel and image.

I know by the way, all of this has something to do with *fitting Thm* but I am just a linear algebra 1 student, so, I'd like to keep things simple for now.

Comment: $dim (ker T^k) + dim (im T^k)=dim V$

Comment: @Jlamprong, First, Thanks. I am familiar with the Dimensions Thm. I want to know what would happen to $kerT^k$, $ImT^k$. in relation to the case of $k-1$.

Comment: Try looking at Artin. This can lead you to some good results on Generalised Eigenspaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you talk about an arbitrary linear operator (on infinite-dimensional spaces). You can say:

- $\ker T^{k} \subset \ker T^{k+1}$;
- $Im T^{k+1} \subset Im T^{k}$.

If you assume you are in a finite dimensional space. From these it follows:

- $\dim ( \ker T^{k} ) \leq \dim(\ker T^{k+1}) $;
- $\dim ( Im T^{k+1} ) \leq \dim(Im T^{k})$.

This one can also conclude from $\dim \ker T^{k} + \dim Im T^{k} = \dim V$.

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ corresponding to the eigenvector $x$, then $\lambda^{k}$ is an eigenvalue of $T^{k}$ corresponding to $x$.

What else do you want to know?

Comment: First of all, many thanks. That's exactly what I was looking for. Can you explain the **meaning** of the subsets equations?

Comment: Saying $\ker T^{k} \subset \ker T^{k+1}$ means that if $x \in \ker T^{k}$, then $x \in \ker T^{k+1}$, i.e. if $T^{k} x = 0$, then $T^{k+1} x = 0$. This is seen easily, since $T^{k+1} x = T T^{k} x = T 0 = 0$. Similar for $Im T^{k+1} \subset Im T^{k}$: if $y = T^{k+1} x$, then by letting $z = T x$, it is seen that $T^{k} z = T^{k} T x = T^{k+1} x = y$.