# prove that $ImT^k$ $\cap$ $KerT^k$ $= 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T:V\rightarrow V$, be linear map such that $\dim V = n$ 
I am trying to prove that to all $k \ge n$:
$\mbox{im}T^k\cap\ker T^k$ $= \{0\}$.
I got stuck somewhere along the way,
I'm a linear algebra 1 student so if you could keep things simple I would appreciate it
Thanks!

Comment: Please add your try.

Comment: Have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646071/linear-operator-tk-effect-on-kertk-and-imtk?rq=1 and see if you can get anything out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Let $k \geq n$. There are two cases: Either $T^k \equiv 0$ or $rank T^k \ > 0$. First case is trivial as $ im T^k = \{0\}$. In the second case, we must have $rank T^l = rank T^{l+1}$ for some $l<n$, by the pigeonhole principle and the fact that rank of $T$ must weakly decrease by each iteration. This means $T$ is an isomorphism when restricted to $im T^l$. This should give you the result.

Comment: thanks alot! can you explain maybe why: the rank of T must weakly decrease by each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by the comment above, the null space power of a linear operator eventually stop growing : $ker T^n=ker T^{n+1}...$ and so on. Here $dim V=n$

now for sake of contradiction suppose, $\alpha$ be a non-zero vector so that there exists a vector $x$ such that $T^{n}(\alpha)=0; T^{n}(x)=\alpha$, clearly we can not have $x\in Ker T^{n}$........ $(*)$. (Since, $\alpha$ is a non-zero vector).

But now we have $T^n(T^n(x))=T^{2n}(x)=0\implies x\in KerT^{2n}=kerT^n$. which contradicts $(*)$

Comment: hey! thanks for your answer, i dont fully understand why the null space grows, and in what conditions does it grow or stay the same, can you please elaborate?

Comment: I would like to request you to prove that if $Ker T^n=Ker T^{n+1}$ for any natural $n$, (not necessarily $n=dim V )$ , then after $n$ we have $ker T^{n}=Ker T^{n+1}=ker T^{n+2}...$  so on. After proving so,note that, $Ker T\subset Ker T^2\subset...$ and so on. (I suppose they are unequal, in case of equality, by the claim i requested you to prove, the chain stops at $n$).that means $dim Ker T<dim Ker T^2<dim ker T^n<...$  but see that, $dim ker T^n$ can be at max $dim V$.( $n\geq 1$) so the chain of the subset must ends atleast at $n=dimV$. (in the most worst situation, it will stop at $n$.)

Comment: i think i understand. so if kerT grows meaning that kerT ⊂ KerT2... then it will only stop growing when $T^i = 0$ ? (i bieng the number where $kerT^i = kerT^{i+1}$)

Comment: to say in simple words, suppose you find that $Ker T^7=Ker T^8$, then you can gurantee that not only $ker T^7=Ker T^8$ is true, also you have $ ker T^7=ker T^8=ker T^9=Ker T^{10} ...$ and so on. that is, the chain actually stops at $7$ (or maybe even earlier)